# Probability of black side of card

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Question:**

So the question is, in a box, there are a number of cards:

- x cards black from both sides
- y cards whote from both sides
- z cards having one side black and one white

So if a person draws a card from the box and show you one side which is black, what is the probability that other side is also black.

**My Approach:**

I personally think that since we have seen one side which is black, the cards white from bpth sides are no longer a part of our sample space. Thus total sample space would be x+z and probability that other side is also black will be x/(x+z).

**Objection:**

However, my friend objects that and says it is an application of Bayes Theorem and I should follow the formula to calculate the probability.

**Counter Argument:**

I think that it would be a case of Bayes Theorem only if we would not know the color of one side then we have probabilities of One side black and other side black given the one side is black for the application of Bayes Theorem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This depends... it is like the monty hall problem.  What thought processes were going through your friend's head when he showed you the card?  Does he decide to only ever show you a black side if at least one of the sides is black?  Or did he pick a side of the card to show you at random?

Comment: The exact mechanism is critical here.  How is it decided which face you are shown?

Comment: If he acts that he picks a side of the card at random to show and shows you that, you will have one answer.  If he checks both sides and if at least one is black he shows you a black side, then you will have a different answer.  If you remain unconvinced, consider the opposite strategy of what side to show where he will always show you a white side if at least one white side exists.  Having been shown a black side only occurs then if both sides are black.

Comment: @lulu which face does not matter as they could be fully white or black and identical black for x & z. Identical white for y & z

Comment: It certainly does matter. If he is determined to show you a black face, if possible, that's very different than if he shows you a random face.

Comment: Oh you meant that way. He does shows one side and that is black for sure. He determined to show a black side

Comment: If you are sure of that mechanism, then seeing the black face just means that the card isn't of type of $y$, so the answer you give is correct.  But this ambiguity is precisely the source of your debate with your friend.  Convince yourself that the answer is different if the card is drawn at random AND the face is selected at random.

Comment: If the face would have been shown randomly, how different the cae would be?

Comment: @JMoravitz how would it be different for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, the probability will depend heavily on what strategy your friend uses in determining which face to show.

If after drawing a card at random he then chooses which side to show at random, if it happen to be that the side he shows you is black then the probability that the other side is black will be:

$$\frac{2x}{2x+z}$$

If after drawing a card at random he then chooses to show you a black side if at least one of the sides is black, the probability that the other side is black will be:

$$\frac{x}{x+z}$$

The calculation for the second case, you already performed correctly.  The idea being, we know that having seen a black card it was not one of the $y$ cards who have both sides as white.  By removing those from those to consider, each remaining card is equally likely to have been chosen.  That leaves $x$ "good" results out of $x+z$ total equally likely results.

The calculation for the first case, imagine for a moment that each side has a "front" and a "back."  By treating each side separately, we recognize that each of the sides across all cards are equally likely to have been selected.  $2x$ of the faces have an opposite face as also black.  This is out of the $2x+z$ total equally likely black faces that we could have been shown.

Comment: Now its clear. Thanks.